# Element Property shows Enabled always even if the element is disabled

Tags: ios, iphone, ruby, automation, appium

I find in the Appium inspector and even `isenabled?` code, that the element that has `userinteraction = false` shows `enabled = true` in Appium.

This happens when I view element in iOS on both device and simulator.

I need to pass a check, that returns me `enabled = false` if the element is disabled.

I need to know if its an issue with Appium or which property in iOS element, should be modified so that Appium recognises that element status to be True/False based on the element being enabled/disabled respectively.

Comment: I am also facing the same situation. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: Not really. As a work around, for all the disabled elements, we have put a condition for accessibility label to return as false. So we are keeping two checks there, while asserting element with value, we check if its label is false or not, in case of false, we take it as disabled.